# Formula with range on other sheet, range '' not found

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

i got a small problem, i need to multiply two values. One value is the activecell.offset(,-2) and the other is a cell on another sheet. The sheet is the value of a combobox (cbblad).

so the formula i come up with is:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*" & cbBlad.Value & "!N6"
```

after i test the code i get this formula in the cell:

```
=I44*'12.1'!'N6'
```

the problem with the code is that the range N6 is not found because it has those ' ' around it.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a R1C1 formula, so you will need to put the N6 reference in that style as well:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*" & cbBlad.Value & "!R6C14"
```